# Form Evaluation With PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using form and evaluating it through PHP. Here is my form code:

```
<form id="LU" method="post" action="">
<select name="Login_Select" id="LT">
<option value="Please Select LType" selected="selected">Please Select Login Type</option>
<option value="Std">Student</option>
<option value="Fac">Faculity</option>
</select>
<div style="padding-top:1.5%" id="Login">
<p id="LID">Group ID: &nbsp;<input id="LL" name="Log" type="text"/></p>
<p id="LP">Password:&nbsp; <input id="LTP" name="Password" type="password" /></p>
<p id="Err">Invalid ID Or Password!</p>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

And down in the body tag I have a PHP evaluator code like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

But as soon as the page launches it display $_POST array which is empty at that time.

I want that the array will display when user submitted the form so that array has values inserted in text boxes.

Comment: perhaps you're looking for `if(!empty($_POST))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if a post request has been made, you should use:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
```

(instead of `if(isset($_POST))`)

Answer (score 3):

`$_POST`, being a superglobal, is always set.  You may want to check if a certain key is set (`if(isset($_POST['foo']))`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to just check if the submit button value is sent. You are also missing a closing tag for your `Login` div but that's unrelated.

Form:

```
<form id="LU" method="post" action="">
    <select name="Login_Select" id="LT">
        <option value="Please Select LType" selected="selected">Please Select Login Type</option>
        <option value="Std">Student</option>
        <option value="Fac">Faculity</option>
    </select>
    <div style="padding-top:1.5%" id="Login">
    <p id="LID">Group ID: &nbsp;<input id="LL" name="Log" type="text"/></p>
    <p id="LP">Password:&nbsp; <input id="LTP" name="Password" type="password" /></p>
    <p id="Err">Invalid ID Or Password!</p>
    <input id="submit_btn" name="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn'])){
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```